# Is there a limited amount of Chips I can get?

Tags: infinity-blade-3

I want to buy keys with the Chips, but since I just started I'm not sure yet if there is a limit to them or not. It seems like once you finish all tiers of the challenges that you would run out of them. Is this true or can you get them other ways also?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as i can tell, you can either get the chips by finishing the challenges, or finish the additional request in some battle (you will only have 5 chips for it), or buy it. I would use the chips to buy only large keys since the rate for chips->gold is largest for large keys! Use it wisely!